# Unable to create Dynamic dropdown because useState return first null then return with data

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api, use-effect, use-state

I am using fetch API inside useEffect hook for fetching data from API. Inside useEffect I am setting API data inside a varaible `userList` variable but because of `null` initially I am unable to create a dynamic dropdown.

My code is:

```
useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const response = await fetch("https://localhost:44316/api/auth/getavailableusers", {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        
        },
        credentials: "include",
      });
      const content = await response.json();
      setUserList(content);
    })();
  },[]);
```

component:

```
 <div className="mb-3">
            <select
              id="choices-multiple-remove-button"
              placeholder="Select Maximum 5 Members"
              multiple
              onChange={(e) => setGroupUsers(e.target.value)}
            >
              {userList?.map(user => <option value={user?.userId} key={user?.userId}>{user?.name}</option>)}
            </select>
          </div>
```

If I `console.log(userList)` I found first I am getting null after that I am getting data in userList.

[image]

Comment: What is the actual error you are getting?

Comment: There is no error. because of null my dropdown items are not appearing in the dropdown

Comment: When the state gets set the entire component will re-render so that shouldn't matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like another answer states, you should initialize your state first by doing

`useState([]);`

I assume that you don't want to render your Select component before receiving your data.

So try rendering the dropdown only if your array is not empty.

```
<div className="mb-3">
 {userList.length > 0 &&
    <select
    id="choices-multiple-remove-button"
    placeholder="Select Maximum 5 Members"
    multiple
    onChange={(e) => setGroupUsers(e.target.value)}
    >
    {userList?.map(user => <option value={user?.userId} key={user?.userId}>{user?.name}</option>)}
    </select>
}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use initial state as [], i.e. `useState([])`.

Comment: If use emty array as a initial state I get first empty array than I am getting my data. Its a same situation as mine

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see if it is null in your template or just set the initial state to an emtpy array rather than null.

```
<div className="mb-3">
    <select
    id="choices-multiple-remove-button"
    placeholder="Select Maximum 5 Members"
    multiple
    onChange={(e) => setGroupUsers(e.target.value)}
    >
    {userList ? userList?.map(user => <option value={user?.userId} key={user?.userId}>{user?.name}</option>) : []}
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Not Working. Same result